# How to supress string quotations when delimiter is in string in JasperReports?

Tags: csv, jasper-reports

for a csv-Output I will not get the surrounding with "" ,
if a delimiter is in the string.

This happens (correctly) in the newest version 6.4, in older versions (f.e. 3.*), 
the output has no strings.
I want to have it like in the old version:

```
...;-6.638,66;-6.806,72;18.571,43;....
```

now it is surrounded with quotes in standard output :

```
...;"-6.638,66;-6.806,72;18.571,43";....
```

how can I suprress the creation of " "  in the jrxml-File  or how can I overwrite the net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.field.enclosure - Parameter ?

It's a string Textfield , $F{F_PeriodDistribution}

Export property: `net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.field.enclosure -> "`

PS: any supression like string.Replace("\"", "");  in the string field creation doesn't work, because JasperReports generates the quotes later by creation because of the field enclosure flag ...

Comment: could you please share some code outlining what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replace it with

```
       <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement key="textField" style="Arial_8_Normal" mode="Transparent" x="510" y="0" width="50" height="11" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="2d9e6183-f8ef-4fc4-b365-825a4c45f4f6">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{P_WithPeriodDistribution} && $F{F_PeriodDistributionDataSource} == null]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top" rotation="None">
                <font size="5"/>
                <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{F_PeriodDistribution.replace("\"", "")}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```